# Consequent Image stabilization in OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stabilization

I am looking for a stabilization technique/algorithm that works with a set of sequential images, but not a video (each image arrives every 1.2s aprox). OpenCV seems to have this stabilization but over video ([stabilizer](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d6c/classcv_1_1videostab_1_1StabilizerBase.html)), are there any other classes that I can use to stabilize this set of images? Or, is there a way to make it work with this class?

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: can you post sample images in a sequence? Videos are nothing else than sequential images, so if it does not work, the method might just not be great for low-fps-videos, maybe it assumes small movements between images.

Comment: I haven't use this part of OpenCV yet, but by the looks of it you can create a derived `IFrameSource` class that uses a vector (only 3 functions to implement).

Comment: maybe I did not understand the class correctly, but I assumed that the video must already be pre-built before the stabilization, and my problem is that I must stabilize while the images are being received. will this derived IFrameSource class help me with this¿

Comment: @AdriánArroyoPerez: as in [causal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system) ? Video stabilization is of course a specific problem from the broader field of control theory.

Comment: @MSalters i guess that is it, for each new image it must be stabilize just when it arrives

Comment: @api55 - Your comment is pretty close to an answer. You might want to re-post it as such?

Comment: @Adrián Arroyo Perez - In your particular case, can you wait until you've received 'all' of the images/frames before stabilizing, or do you need the results continuously, as the images are being received? The answer might determine whether you can assemble the frames you're getting into a stream that can be fed into stabilizer...

Comment: @ScottSmith Currently we have discarded that option as we would like to postprocess every image after stabilizing it.